# Spring boot war deployment in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

i'm deploy one war generated by maven and Spring boot on Tomcat 7 - Ubuntu 14.04.

When i looking the catalina.out i see lots of 'attempts' to deploy my application like that:

```
INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)

    2016-07-26 21:02:34.266  INFO 9167 --- [.br-startStop-1] b.c.d.DoutorLicitaApplication            : Starting DoutorLicitaApplication
2016-07-26 21:02:24.716  INFO 9167 --- [.br-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-07-26 21:02:24.747  INFO 9167 --- [.br-startStop-1] b.c.d.DoutorLicitaApplication            : Started DoutorLicitaApplication in 5.642 seconds (JVM running for 52.876)
Jul 26, 2016 9:02:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

i would to know why so many attempts to deploy, this process takes over minute

My main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class DoutorLicitaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DoutorLicitaApplication.class);
    }
}
```

and my pom properties

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>br.com.doutorlicita.DoutorLicitaApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
```

I create right now one vbox with the same configuration as EC2 on my computer and this error dont happens.

UPDATE:
I see that the problem only occurs when having set the virtualhost

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you attach the full log?

Comment: Could you please post your main class here?